# First uses of names having power?

Tags: names, origins

Often, in science fiction, knowing a person's true name gives you power over it.  One such example is in the Inheritance Cycle series.  Also, sometimes only knowing the person's name can give you power over them as well, as in the Doctor Who episode The Shakespeare Code.  What were the earliest examples of names having power over the owner?

Comment: I think this traces back to demonic folk-lore, where speaking the demon's name somehow gives you power over it.

Comment: [Per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_name#Folklore), there are many early examples of this in myth and folklore. I would argue that in contemporary fantasy literature, it was largely popularized by Ursula Le Guin's _Earthsea_ series.

Comment: It is a very old superstition. SciFi writers undoubtedly drew from ancient history. Related: [Does knowing a spirit's name give special powers in controlling that spirit according to Christian theology?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/30842)

Comment: Here's the [TV Tropes link](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IKnowYourTrueName?from=Main.TrueName) for this, if you dare...

Comment: DARN YOU @JoeL. !!! :}

Comment: @recognizer YES! Someone had to mention Earthsea. +1 :-D

Comment: YHWH in Judaism.

Comment: @randal'thor Had to mention it, then left it to someone else to write up a proper answer :P

Comment: @WadCheber Lexible said it first!

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The idea of a *true name* being linked to the essence of an individual or object's being is [an ancient philosophical and mystical concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_name) predating the novel, and the fantasy and science fiction genres.

@recognizer commented on the notable use of true names in [Ursula Le Guin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursula_K._Le_Guin)'s [*Earthsea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earthsea) milieu:

> By the Illusion-Change you can make it look like a diamond—or a flower or a fly or a flame—”, The rock flickered from shape to shape as he named them, and returned to rock. “But that is mere seeming. Illusion fools the beholder’s senses; it makes him see and hear and feel that the thing is changed. But it does not change the thing. To change this rock into a jewel, you must change its true name... And to do that... even to so small a scrap of the world, is to change the world. It is the art of the Master Changer, and you will learn it, when you are ready to learn it.”
>   —The Master Hand from [*A Wizard of Earthsea*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Wizard_of_Earthsea)

The fairy-tale [*Rumpelstiltskin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rumpelstiltskin) is a European folkloric example of a person's true name conferring magical power over them. The point of the Rumpelstiltskin tales is that a young woman is freed from his coercive power by learning and saying Rumpelstiltskin's name. Variations on this theme have appeared in contemporary literature, for example, [Susanna Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susanna_Clarke)'s story "On Lickerish Hill" appearing in [*The Ladies of Grace Adieu*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ladies_of_Grace_Adieu_and_Other_Stories) deals with a similar theme. [William Gibson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Gibson)'s anthemic [cyberpunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyberpunk) novel [*Neuromancer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuromancer) provides a science-fiction version of the true name, wherein an artificial intelligence seeks to transcend its own limitations by learning its own name.

> I don't know. You might say what I am is basically defined by the fact that I don't know, because I can't know. I am that which knoweth not the word.
>   —The AI Wintermute from *Neuromancer*

The idea of the true name also has a long history in religious mysticism. For example, pious Jews [utter aloud the honorific 'Adonai' to refer to god, rather than the name of god, 'Yahweh' (יהוה, or YHWH)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton). [Arthur C. Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke) invokes the concept of god's true name in a 20th century science fiction short story "[The Nine Billion Names of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Nine_Billion_Names_of_God)" to tell a tale of early computer automation permuting through all possible phonemes to find all possible versions of god's true name (with an amusing conclusion to the tale, to be sure).

Linguistic research published the same week you asked this question points at the possibility that [spoken language may "tap a universal code,"](http://news.sciencemag.org/brain-behavior/2015/08/spoken-language-could-tap-universal-code) so some of the philosophic ideas behind the "true name" get run-time in the sciences (whether or not they are accepted or rejected, is, naturally for the process of science to develop :).

**Conclusion:** The idea of the true name is not a recent invention, and has a long history in philosophy, folktales, and religious and secular mysticism, and these histories have proven fertile subject matter in contemporary speculative fiction.

Comment: Cf. Genesis 2:19-20 *and by extension Acts 19:15*.

Comment: TVTropes lists "I Know Your True Name" as "older than dirt" - meaning preceeding the greek alphabet.

Comment: Isis goes back to at least the late Old Kingdom and made use of Ra's true name, which would be an earlier example than Judaism. I think there are examples in Sumerian belief too, but am not sure.

Comment: @JonHanna -- Strictly speaking, Out-of-Universe, yes. In-Universe the Genesis bit goes back to "In the beginning", a time which predates the Old Kingdom ;) Additionally I don't think that Egyptian legend-lore had much influence on the modern scifi/fantasy's **first** use of True Names, whereas the influence from Judaism cannot be dismissed.

Comment: @user23715 the Sumerian case would go back to before "in the beginning" if one goes by Archbishop Usher's interpretation, which is quite popular as fanon in some quarters. As for the influence on sci-fi and fantasy, I'd argue that not only did it have some influence directly, but it also very much influenced 19th and 20th century magicians, who in turn had a great influence on genre writing.

Comment: @JonHanna -- "before 'In the beginning'"? Non sequitur that. And I'm not familiar with Archbishop Usher, **Usher**, vis-a-vis the songs *Nice* or *OMG*, I know of though. -- FWIW my initial comment here was used as an aside in a term paper I did for a Modern Lit class a couple years back on Vinge's *True Names... and Other Dangers*.

Comment: @user23715 Archbisop James Usher came to the conclusion that the events of Genesis chapter 1 took place in 4004 BCE. A bit before the Old Kingdom, but sometime after the rise of Sumer.

Comment: Might want to add the translation for "Adonai" to contrast it with the name.  It's literally "My Lord", and historically it's been used the same way the English word is (i.e. both to refer to God or to a human lord/superior)

Comment: @Bobson Meh... Amended (briefly, since the text links to an in-depth article on the topic) for clarity... and thank you for the input!